# Read specific data from notepad

Tags: vb.net, notepad

I have a notepad with some unscrambled data as shown below and would like to read data from that text file and populate data to individual textboxes.

This is how my input looks likes:

```
========================================================
Modified Date : 5/20/2019 8:45:56 AM     Modified by : 123
ID : 18677544
OLD Values:

First Name        Last Name        Middle Initial    
--------------    --------------  -----------------
John              Humpty        


NEW Values:

First Name        Last Name        Middle Initial    
--------------    --------------  -----------------
George            Louis 

========================================================
```

This is my code

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\123.txt"
    Dim searchTarget = "Modified Date"
     For Each line In File.ReadAllLines(path)
        If line.Contains(searchTarget) Then ' found it!
          Dim toBeSearched As String = "Modified Date : "
          Dim code As String = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(toBeSearched) + toBeSearched.Length)
          txtModifiedDate.Text = code// Here I'm getting Modified By value also but I need only the Modified Date in this textbox similarly for others
     Exit For ' then stop
    End If
Next line
```

As per preciousbetine getting overload exception error

[image]

Updated :

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic - how do I read the data(ie I need to grab the value for Modified Date, First Name, Last Name etc and populate those values in textboxes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sample text file you gave is how it always looks like, then this should work.

I hardcoded most of the values but for the text file above, the below code works:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Dim path As String = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\123.txt"
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    lines.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(path))

    Dim tmpArray = lines(1).Split(" "c)

   '******Update*******************
    Dim tmplist As New List(Of String)
    tmplist.Add(tmpArray(3))
    tmplist.Add(tmpArray(4))
    tmplist.Add(tmpArray(5))

    Dim strModifiedDate As String = String.Join(" ", tmplist.ToArray) 'Get the date by joining the date, time

    '************************ 
    strModifiedDate.Text = strModifiedDate

    Dim strModifiedBy As String = tmpArray(UBound(tmpArray))
    strModifiedBy.Text = strModifiedBy

    tmpArray = lines(2).Split(":"c)
    strID.Text = tmpArray(1).Trim

    Dim tmpStr As String = lines(7).Split(" "c)(0)
    strOldFirstName.Text = tmpStr

    tmpStr = lines(7).Substring(strOldFirstName.Text.Length).Trim
    strOldLastName.Text = tmpStr

    tmpStr = lines(14).Split(" "c)(0)
    strNewFirstName.Text = tmpStr
    tmpStr = lines(14).Substring(strNewFirstName.Text.Length).Trim
    strNewLastName.Text = tmpStr
End Sub
```

[image: Example Output]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Please check the error i'm getting

Comment: And I'm getting both first and lastnames in one textbox

Comment: @Kitty are you sure you used the exact code i posted? You should get exactly the same output in the image.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now the date problem solved but still the names are adding to the same text box as shown above.

Comment: @Kitty are you sure the data is in exactly the same format as the one in the question?

Comment: Hey Thanks.. I can able to manage..And one more last question is how do I loop through the entire file to display all the names one after the other ?

Comment: Can you post an example of the text file you want to loop through? The code above works for only the file in your question. Well, to do that, you'll need to do a search for all the lines containing the string `name`, then extract the values from there.